# Unmet dependencies while trying to install mysql in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I tried to install / remove and reinstall / fix Mysql and Workbench in Ubuntu 20.04 but allways get this message:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is to be installed
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
 mysql-community-test : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libjson-perl but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mysql-community-server-core but it is not installable
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try sudo apt --fix-broken install this comes out:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
 mysql-community-test : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libjson-perl but it is not installed
                        Depends: mysql-community-server-core but it is not installable
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.20-2ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I'm sorry, I'm sure there is a easy solution.. but I can't find it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fits better to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying
`sudo apt autoremove libmysqlclient21 mysql-client mysql-community-test mysql-server`

If any other new unmet dependency shows up append the package at the end of the above command.

This shows up because when there are several packages dependent upon each other, removing only one will break the dependency count.

So removing them simultaneously ensures no broken packages.

Revert if you find any other issue

Comment: It always remains the same error. How can I fix the issue?